# Date not getting correctly using NSDate In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I want to print date [1,2,3.... current date] but not getting correct result. 
Because when I set first day is "1" in my code, the output in [2,3,4]. And when I set day is "0". It result show correct but show an extra date [1,2,3,4,5]. And today is 4th October 2016, as my time zone.

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)
    let year =  components.year
    let month = components.month
    let day =  1  // Output is [2,3,4]
 // let day =  0   than o/p [1,2,3,4,5]


    dateFormatatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    monthNameLabel.text = dateFormatatter.stringFromDate(date)

    startDate.year = year
    startDate.month = month
    startDate.day = day
    let startDateNSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(startDate)!

    var dateStart = startDateNSDate // first date
    let endDate = NSDate() // last date

    dateFormatatter.dateFormat = "dd"


    while dateStart.compare(endDate) != .OrderedDescending {
        // print(fmt.stringFromDate(date))
        // Advance by one day:
        dateStart = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: dateStart, options: [])!


        let dateFormat1 = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat1.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

        dateArrayCalendar.addObject(dateFormatatter.stringFromDate(dateStart))
        dateArrayForCompare.addObject(dateFormat1.stringFromDate(dateStart))

    }
```

And I want result like this [1,2,3,4]

**And Same issue Here**

```
let componentsForCompare = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: date)
        let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(componentsForCompare)!
        print(startOfMonth)//2016-09-30 18:30:00 +0000
        print(dateFormatatter.stringFromDate(startOfMonth)) //01
```

Its give different Outputs

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment your date *at the end* of the while loop, rather than at the start:

```
while dateStart.compare(endDate) != .OrderedDescending {
    // print(fmt.stringFromDate(date))
    // Advance by one day:

    let dateFormat1 = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat1.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    dateArrayCalendar.addObject(dateFormatatter.stringFromDate(dateStart))
    dateArrayForCompare.addObject(dateFormat1.stringFromDate(dateStart))

    dateStart = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: dateStart, options: [])!
}
```

Comment: When I ran this code I got `["01", "02", "03", "04"]` - Here is my code straight from my playground - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/278447c9678428fa584319a4d95c2fac  Your code wasn't complete in your question so I had to declare some variables, maybe this caused me to get a different result?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If I set day = 1 and check in my dataArray calendar it show first date is 30-09-2016 in backend. Check uploaded image

Comment: That is showing you the time in UTC, not local time,  Depending on the time difference between your local time and UTC,  it may be the 30th in UTC when it is the 1st in your time zone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124859/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ideveloper).